# How to implements node into JTable?

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to build a JtreeTable because, I want to create a JTable with Node. In this table I must show Category and sub-category, so I want to built a JTable with all the Categories, if the Category has a sub-category I also have to show it.

So I have this code

```
 DefaultMutableTreeNode   node = buildNodeFromString();   
 DefaultTreeModel model = new DefaultTreeModel(node);  
 JTree tree = new JTree(model);  
 JFrame f = new JFrame();  
 f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
 f.add(tree);  
 f.setSize(300,300);  
 f.setLocation(200,200);  
 f.setVisible(true);  

 private DefaultMutableTreeNode buildNodeFromString() {
    String qqq= "node1/node2/node3/node4";
    DefaultMutableTreeNode node, lastNode = null, root = null;

    String[] s = qqq.split("/");
    for (String str : s) {
        node = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(str);     
        if (root == null)
            root = node;
        if (lastNode != null)
            lastNode.add(node);
        lastNode = node;
     }

    return root;
}
```

This code works, but I want to show a JTreeTable like as normal JTable.
It is possible to do it?

**EDIT**

This is an example that I want

[image]

Comment: Not sure I completely understand, however, if you just want to display the data in a `JTable`, then you will need to construct a `TableModel` which flattens the tree table in some way

Comment: I know that I need the TableModel, but I want to display the tada with the node, so I think that I have nedd the JTreeTable

Comment: Ahh, okay, so what's the problem?  Your code example doesn't use `JTreeTable` ... not that there is such a thing, but you could use `JXTreeTable` from Swing Labs, SwingX project

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have fint that I want